# How to get data from relation in Laravel used in with()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am getting data from multiple tables in relation with each other. But in one of the relation I want to get `userAnswers` records by `where('user_id, $userID)`. What is correct syntax for it

```
public function survey_completed_show($userSurvey, $userID)
{
    $userSurvey =  UserSurvey::with('survey.questions.userAnswers')->find($userSurvey);

    return view('surveys.conducted-answers', compact('userSurvey'));
}
```

I just want to get answers of the selected User, I am currently getting all answers by each user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use deep `with`:

```
$userSurvey =  UserSurvey::with(['survey'=>function($query)use( $userID){
            $query->with(['questions'=>function($query)use( $userID){
                    $query->with(['userAnswers'=>function($query)use( $userID){
                        $query->where('user_id', $userID);
                    }]);
            }]);
            }])->find($userSurvey);
```

Comment: Yes, It was another query which is resolved by you. Deep new is new for me thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only need to filter the relation and not the UserSurvey you might wanna try this

```
public function survey_completed_show($userSurvey, $userID)
{
    $userSurvey =  UserSurvey::with(['survey.questions.userAnswers' => function($q) use ($userID){
        $q->where('user_id', $userID);
    }])->find($userSurvey);

    return view('surveys.conducted-answers', compact('userSurvey'));
}
```